# Cannot destructure property 'isActive' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

Using script setup in vue3, I have code like this in template

```
   ...
          <router-link
            v-for="t in tas"
            :key="t.text"
            custom
            :to="`/dashboard/${t.type}`"
            v-slot="{ isActive, navigate }"
          >
            <div
              :class="{ active: isActive }"
              @click="navigate"
            >
              {{ t.text }}
            </div>
          </router-link>
   ...
```

Its throwing error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isActive' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.` when running a simple test

```
  it('match snapshot', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MYView, {
      stubs: ['router-link'],
    });
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stub it using RouterLinkStub, see https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#routerlinkstub